# python import failing in runExec in java

Tags: java, python, import

I have a python script that I want to run in java.
It works perfectly in terminal when I run 
    $ python /Users/myuser/Projects/hgvs/hgvs/tests/test_gsg_variants.py

Currently I have this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python /Users/afrieden/Projects/hgvs/hgvs/tests/test_gsg_variants.py");
String s = null;
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(s);
}

// read any errors from the attempted command
System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

And I am getting this error output:

```
Here is the standard output of the command:
```

Here is the standard error of the command (if any):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/afrieden/Projects/hgvs/hgvs/tests/test_gsg_variants.py", line 2, in <module>
  import hgvs
ImportError: No module named hgvs

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why is it failing to find this import?

EDIT:  sys lists are now the same and import error has gone away.  Works fine in terminal python but fails when I use java to do a system call as per the same code.

```
/Users/afrieden/Projects/hgvs/hgvs/tests
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygr-0.8.2-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyodbc-3.0.7-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
/Users/afrieden/Projects/hgvs/build/lib/
/Users/afrieden/pythonLib/pygr-0.8.2/
/Users/afrieden/pythonLib/pygr-0.8.2/pygr/seqfmt.pyx
/Users/afrieden/pythonLib/pygr-0.8.2/pygr/seqfmt.c
```

However I am now getting this error in the java system call:

Here is the standard error of the command (if any):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/afrieden/Projects/hgvs/hgvs/tests/test_gsg_variants.py", line 24, in <module>
genome = SequenceFileDB('/Users/afrieden/test/hg/hg18.fa')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygr-0.8.2-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pygr/seqdb.py", line 424, in __init__
seqLenDict = classutil.open_shelve(fullpath, 'r')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygr-0.8.2-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pygr/classutil.py", line 457, in open_shelve
return dbfile.shelve_open(filename, flag=mode, useHash=useHash)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygr-0.8.2-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pygr/dbfile.py", line 167, in shelve_open
d = open_index(filename, flag, useHash, mode) # construct Shelf only if OK
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygr-0.8.2-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pygr/dbfile.py", line 106, in open_index
d = open_anydbm(filename, flag)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygr-0.8.2-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pygr/dbfile.py", line 46, in open_anydbm
raise WrongFormatError(msg)
pygr.dbfile.WrongFormatError: db type could not be determined
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do all of your directories have a `__init__.py` in them?

Comment: Check that you don't have multiple `python` executables installed. Check that it works from a different working directory in terminal. Check whether PYTHONPATH is different or `sys.path`.

Comment: directory of the failed import has __init__.py in it.  How can I check pythonpath and sys.path

Comment: Add this at the very top of your script: import sys \n<-(a real one) print(sys.path) and then run from commandline and java.

Comment: lists are slightly different than one another

Comment: Why do you show `WrongFormatError`? Have you fixed `ImportError`?

Comment: yes, added the egg files to import and import error has gone away.

Answer (score 1):

I followed another approach with [jython](http://www.jython.org/downloads.html)

```
    PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
    String fname = "/Users/afrieden/Projects/hgvs/hgvs/tests/test_gsg_variants.py";
    String in = "/Users/afrieden/Projects/hgvs/hgvs/tests/in.txt";
    InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(in);
    String out = "/Users/afrieden/Projects/hgvs/hgvs/tests/err.txt";
    InputStream errStream = new FileInputStream(in);
    interp.execfile(fname);

    String s = null;
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errStream));


    System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }

    // read any errors from the attempted command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }

    stdInput.close();
    stdError.close();
```

I think this will help you unless the rights of the file are not right.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use full python exec path like

```
/usr/bin/python
```

and check for permission of the mentioned file. It need to be executable by any other. like *755*. I don't know it going help you or not but try it.